# Change browser language preference programmatically

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-8, language-agnostic, qtp

**How can I change the browser language preference setting programmatically?**

In the scenario at hand, I want to start the webapp in different languages. The app delivers the language as requested in the browser's language preferences, so I want to reconfigure the browser to English, perform some steps, then reconfigure the browser to a different language, and repeat those steps.

For automation, I'd use VBScript (using some COM server?) or QTP (which basically is just a VBScript client in this context), but I don't think this should matter.

Comment: The language can be changed in the registry (`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International\AcceptLanguage`), but I'm not aware of a way to have IE reload that value on the fly. You'd have to restart the browser to update the setting.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen one solution using SendMessage and some notification message. It was hundreds of lines in C#, obviously because a simple message is not all there is to it. I think I´ll use the reg key/value, though, and re-start all browsers. Maybe then the new setting's guaranteed to be active.

Comment: It's not as bad...here is the link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20756/Change-Internet-Explorer-Proxy-Setting-without-R

Comment: I have bad experience with the settings changed message since in other contexts (setting an anvironment variable), the (there implicit) message timeout is so high that it takes > 30 seconds until the SendMessage call comes back if the desktop has lots of windows that don't handle the message (and thus timeout). I hate integrating stuff that blocks for 1 second or so per desktop window (or similar)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Ansgar does not disagree, I post the final result of researching this topic:

It seems there is **no better way than updating `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International\AcceptLanguage`, and (at least) broadcasting a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message via `SendMessage`** so every process in the current session sees this change immediately.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20756/Change-Internet-Explorer-Proxy-Setting-without-R for good examples how to do that.

Comment: Doh. Yet another answer of mine accepted by me. Shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

do what google does (rather used to do)....

add a language parameter to your query string from your app...

eg. google.com/?ln=id&from=myApp

on the sessionstart event handler.... determine the ln parameter of the request and redirect the request to the appropriate web page versions, provide an English fallback if their system language is not supported by your site.
or
Add a translation widget to your website (bing.com/translate)... to allow visitors to use machine/human generated translations.

Comment: What? :) I am not writing the app, I am testing it. Thanks anyway